# Calling Javascript function on browser close

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

I have a site, now what I want is when user switch to some external site, then an Ad should be popped up, and also when user close the browser window, the Ad should get popup, I have used onunload, but it shows the message on clicking every link, and also I used on beforeunload, it does almost everything, but it do the same as onunload...

Please anyone have some idea how should I achieve this?

Comment: I don't want to visit this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't prevent popup appearing on page refresh, but does this job as requested:

```
<script>
var isLinkClicked = false;

// Either plain JS solution:
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var l=links.length;
while (l--) {
    links[l].addEventListener("click", function() {
       isLinkClicked = true;
    }, false);
} 

// Or jQuery solution:
$("a").live("click", function() {
       isLinkClicked = true;
});


// And then Unload event listener:
window.addEventListener("unload", function(evt) {
    if (isLinkClicked) {
       isLinkClicked = false;
       return false;
    }

    // here comes the rest of the code
}, false);
</script>
```